# Why the datatypes in Pandas are different from those in SQL

Tags: python, sqlite

I am a newbie in SQLite and Python and get in circles in the topic.

I import a SQLite table 
[SQL Table Column Data Type](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2wT-we56FkGcnhKZFVQUFBkajQ/edit) into Python

Using Code

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\\SQLite\\aaa.sqlite")
    df=pd.read_sql(sql="select * from C",con=conn,coerce_float=True)
```

When I check the datatype in Python.
Some are Objects

```
 df.dtypes

WD             float64
Manpower       float64
2nd             object
CTR             object
2ndU           float64
T1              object
T2              object
T3              object
T4              object
T5              object
```

Do you know why the Python convert some columns from float64 to Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas would return a DataFrame with columns of dtype `object` if the column contains at least one value which is not a float. For example, a string -- even an empty string -- would force the entire column to be of object dtype:

```
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

filename = '/tmp/test.sqlite'
with sqlite3.connect(filename) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS C')
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE C (CTR float)')
    sql = 'INSERT INTO C VALUES (?)'
    args = [(x, ) for x in np.random.random(5)] + [('',)]
    cursor.executemany(sql, args)
    df = pd.read_sql(sql="SELECT * FROM C",
                     con=conn, coerce_float=True)
    print(df)
    #           CTR
    # 0   0.1205763
    # 1   0.5859016
    # 2   0.9511995
    # 3  0.08459435
    # 4   0.8094845
    # 5            
    print(df.dtypes)
```

yields

```
CTR    object
dtype: object
```